# Any information about these Harry Potter cards?

Tags: harry-potter

I am missing just 3 of these cards, but have no information about the collection apart from that it contains 36 cards in total.

Missing cards: 31-34-36

EDIT:
I have found these cards from a private owner in a second hand app (actually, those 2 on ebay are from the seller I bought them from, but he has no information or the cards that I am missing.)

Text on the back: "HARRY POTTER characters, names and related indicia are trademarks of Warner Bros @ 2001 WB SHIELD: TM & @ 2001 Warner Bros".

I need more information or any leads that could help me to find a way to finish this collection or at least a way to find more information about them.  These are the last 3 cards of my entire collection of Harry Potter collectibles.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  So what is your question?  Do you want a source for the missing cards (probably off-topic) or information about the set?  You also haven't given us much to work with here..

Comment: Perhaps the text on the back of the cards might hold a clue, could you quote it. It's also worth taking the [tour] and referring to the [help] for guidance.

Comment: I'm not very good at using the Enhance button, but it looks like the back of the cards does credit Warner Brothers, which suggests it postdates the movie, although these look like book illustrations. Possibly not an American product since it says "Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone".

Comment: Hi and welcome, this is obviously not a shopping question but we do need more info as other posters have requested. Please can you also upload an image without your personal email address here, in an [edit]?

Comment: And how did you come about the cards? Inheritance? Rubbage bin find? Thrift store? Supermarket?

Comment: @FuzzyBoots FWIW, the text appears to read "HARRY POTTER characters, names and related indicia are trademarks of Warner Bros @ 2001 WB [something] & @ 2001 Warner Bros"  Note that the title is given as "Harry Potter and the **Philosopher's** Stone," so this is likely UK market-specific.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots - The art style is consistent with WB's premovie merch from 2000/2001.

Comment: Thanks for editing the information in! I've deleted a bunch of comments talking about shopping, as that's not the sort of question we cater for here. What might work is if you and @FuzzyBoots talking [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58631/the-restaurant-at-the-end-of-the-universe), and when you find the more details post it as a self-answer here. This is so that anybody who comes with the same question gets a useful answer, not just where *your* missing cards are from.